# Problem while rendering SVG file in HTML (Chatbot icon) in Chrome on Windows 10

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to render an SVG chatbot icon in HTML but due to some issues, it is not rendering correctly in Chrome but it is working as expected in Firefox on Windows 10.

Here is the SVG Chatbot icon

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#ff000f;}.cls-2{fill:#fff;}</style></defs><title>Codi Button</title><g id="kółko"><circle class="cls-1" cx="32" cy="32" r="32"/></g><g id="Lewe_ucho" data-name="Lewe ucho"><rect class="cls-2" x="9" y="26" width="2" height="14"/></g><g id="Prawe_ucho" data-name="Prawe ucho"><rect class="cls-2" x="53" y="26" width="2" height="14"/></g><g id="Głowa"><path class="cls-2" d="M14,20l-1,1V44.9l1,1H25.75l15,8,1.35-1.34L38.67,45.9H50l1-1V21l-1-1ZM49,43.9H37l-.89,1.46,2.74,5.24L26.47,44,26,43.9H15V22H49Z"/></g><g id="Buzia"><rect class="cls-2" x="28" y="37" width="8" height="2"/></g><g id="Prawe_oko" data-name="Prawe oko"><path class="cls-2" d="M40,30a2,2,0,0,1,2,2h2a4,4,0,0,0-8,0h2A2,2,0,0,1,40,30Z"/></g><g id="Lewe_oko" data-name="Lewe oko"><path class="cls-2" d="M24,30a2,2,0,0,1,2,2h2a4,4,0,0,0-8,0h2A2,2,0,0,1,24,30Z"/></g><g id="Antena"><path class="cls-2" d="M36,14a4,4,0,1,0-5,3.85L31,21h2l0-3.14A4,4,0,0,0,36,14Zm-4,2a2,2,0,1,1,2-2A2,2,0,0,1,32,16Z"/></g></svg>
```

I need to display the above SVG icon as our new Chatbot icon. Could you please tell me where I am going wrong?

[Link](https://codepen.io/shajiindia/pen/KKwWBQw) to the already existing Chatbot icon (Codepen) <<<- This is working as expected

[Link](https://codepen.io/shajiindia/pen/gObmjbz) to the new proposed Chatbot icon (Codepen) <<<--- This is not working in Chrome but it works in Firefox (something seems to be broken)

Could you please throw more light on the topic. Any help is highly appreciated.

**Note**: I am using Windows 10 for testing this issue (in both Chrome and Firefox)

Best Regards,

Shaji Kalidasan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the svg tag, and add the height and width, that's the obvious difference between the two codepens.

```
<svg width="84" height="84" viewBox="0 0 84 84" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Cristopher. It is working like a champ.